# Formulário com slot vue3

Tags: vue.js

Criei um formulário que será um componente genérico para poder usar ele em vários métodos(put,post), colouqei um slot dentro dele para poder trocar os métodos de acordo com a necessidade, mas não consigo pegar os dados pelo os eventos dos botões.

```
<template>
    <form>
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" v-model="form.nome">
        <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
        <input type="text" id="sobrenome" v-model="form.sobrenome">
        <div class="group_btn">
            <slot/>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

quando chamo o componente form

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Finalizar compra</h2>
        <FormPadrao>
            <button class="btn">Salvar</button>
        </FormPadrao>
    </div>
</template>
```

já tentei usando o $emit só que não deu certo, claro que estou fazendo errado. kkkk

Answer (score -1):

Voce precisa dar um atributo *name* para o slot e depois utilizar esse name como referência ao slot.

```
<FormPadrao>
  <template v-slot:o-nome-dado-ao-slot>
      <button class="btn">Salvar</button>
  </template>
</FormPadrao>
```